# Что такое функция Add внутри класса с интерфейсом IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

В данном коде функция Add вызывается при инициализации коллекций:

```
    class Numbers: IEnumerable
    {
        private List<string> internalList = new List<string>();
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => internalList.GetEnumerator();

        public void Add(int value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Numbers nums = new Numbers() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        foreach (var num in nums )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + num);
        }
    }
```

Хотелось бы уточнить подробности работы данного метода (Add), т.к. информации по нему я нигде не нашел и мне до конца не ясно то, как он устроен изнутри.

Comment: Похоже это https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers

Comment: «как он устроен изнутри» — а никак, сами реализуйте какое хотите устройство

Comment: [Инициализаторы коллекций](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)

Comment: @andreymal. Хотелось бы узнать как этот метод описан и где

Comment: @SHUSTRIK Так он никак и не устроен. Для каждого класса он реализован по своему, IEnumerable это просто интерфейс

Comment: В вашем коде `Add` - это ваша прихоть, вы ее сами туда добавили, сами ее реализовали, интерфейс не требует от вас данного метода! Я думаю, теперь вы понимаете, что ваш вопрос не корректен? Что она там делает - спросите у себя. [IEnumerable](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/IEnumerable.cs) - это интерфейс, который требует от вас реализовать только одно `GetEnumerator()`, ничего более, ибо энумераторы не обязаны ничего добавлять, их задача только перечислить, а вот `IList` да, должны иметь `Add()`.

Comment: Всё верно, метод `Add` не имеет никакого отношения к интерфейсам `IEnumerable` или `IEnumerable<T>`. Да и если бы имел, то интерфейс это грубо говоря шаблон внешнего програмного API класса, просто обязует вас реализовать те или иные публичные члены. На внутреннюю реализацию чего-либо интерфейсы не влияют, вы сами пишете какой хотите код. А так да, самый первый комментарий от @andreymal скорее всего в тему.